# Python/K-means Clustering: Color centroids with random colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I've built a Kmeans clustering in Python upon data imported from a .txt file. I've generated 100 centroids, and there are two figures being ploted with Matplotlib to show those centroids: one figure containg the cloud of points (originated from the .txt file), what represents the data **before** the clustering, and another figure containing black stars to mark each centroid.

What should I do to plot each centroid in a specific color chosen randomically, instead of the black stars? What means that each centroid group of points would be in a different color.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


#building the 22797x3 array: 


#loading the first array from .txt file, 22797x400 long.
array = np.loadtxt('C:\Scripts/final_array_2.txt', usecols=range(400))  

array = np.float32(array)



#plotting data before the clustering:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(result[:, 0], result[:, 1], result[:, 2], alpha = 0.1)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')



# Initializing KMeans, plotting clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=100)
# Fitting with inputs
kmeans = kmeans.fit(result)
# Predicting the clusters
labels = kmeans.predict(result)
# Getting the cluster centers
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(result[:, 0], result[:, 1], result[:, 2])
ax.scatter(C[:, 0], C[:, 1], C[:, 2], marker='*', c='#050505', s=1000)

plt.show()
```

***Results of the code above***

**Data before the clustering:**
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXa7R.png

**Data after the cluster with the black stars:**https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u4JY.png

**What I need to get (similar example,not the same cloud of points):**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5oDT.png
In this case it would be 100 colors, not just three.

Any help?

Comment: You can specify the color for each plotted point by ``c=z``, where ``z`` is some array of the same shape than ``C[:,0]``. AFAIK, the labels of KMeans are enumerated by the order of the centers, so ``c=range(len(C[:,1]))``. Note that this is not random, however you could shuffle the array if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `kmeans.cluster_centers_`returns the center of each found cluster. What you need is to change the color of each data point by it's label. Using the iris dataset as an example

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = iris.data[:,0:3]
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
z=data[:,2]
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans = kmeans.fit(data)
labels = kmeans.predict(data)

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ColorsA=plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1,5),alpha=0.8) #Equally spaced color 
for i in range(5): #Labels of the clusters 
    xL=[]
    yL=[]
    zL=[]
    for k in range(len(x)):
        if labels[k]==i: #Data points of each cluster 
            xL.append(x[k])
            yL.append(y[k])
            zL.append(z[k])

    ax.scatter(xL,yL,zL,c=ColorsA[i])
```

[image]

Hope it helps